# sentencias preparadas WARNING mysqli_stmt_fetch(); Couldn't fetch mysqli_stmt

Tags: php, mysql

estoy haciendo un formulario de cambio de contraseña en el form todo funciona bien pero en mi .PHP tengo el siguiente codigo:

```
$contra = $_POST['contraseñaanterior'];
    $contrasena = $_POST['nuevacontraseña'];
    $user = $_POST['usuario'];
    $contrasenahash = password_hash($contrasena, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
    $query = mysqli_prepare($con, "SELECT  contraseña from usuarios where idusuario = ?;");
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($query, "i",$user);
    $query->execute();
    mysqli_stmt_bind_result($query,$contraseña);
    while (mysqli_stmt_fetch($query)) {
      if (password_verify($contra,$contraseña)) {
        $update = mysqli_prepare($con, "UPDATE `analisis`.`usuarios` SET `contraseña` = ?  WHERE `idusuario` = ?;");
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($update, "si",$contrasenahash,$user );
        if (!$update->execute()) {
            echo "Error  (" . $update->errno . ") " . $update->error;
        }else{
            echo "contraseña actualizada";
        }
        mysqli_stmt_close($update);
      }
      else {
          echo "error";
      }
  }
    mysqli_stmt_close($query);
```

Con esto verifico la contraseña anterior y actualizo, si actualiza la contraseña pero me tira un WARMING `mysqli_stmt_fetch(); Couldn't fetch mysqli_stmt`

Comment: @shadow el `UPDATE` no se puede hacer con el mismo statement del `SELECT`, son dos cosas distintas.

Comment: De todos modos esa no es la mejor forma de hacerlo. Para este caso yo usaría una transacción, preparando la consulta una sola vez y buscando la forma de enviarle los posibles valores una sola vez y ejecutando una sola vez, pero esa es ya otra historia. Si te parece escribiré una respuesta, corrigiendo la mezcla de estilos de que tienes, la cual es una mala práctica. Recomendaría que uses en todo tu código el estilo orientado a objetos, porque es mucho más claro y mucho más breve.

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/88412/discussion-on-question-by-arglez35-sentencias-preparadas-warning-mysqli-stmt-fet).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El error ocurría debido a que se estaba intentando un `UPDATE` cuando todavía no se había terminado de recuperar todos los datos del conjunto de resultados que trajo el `SELECT`.

En este caso la solución no es cerrar el statemente del `SELECT` dentro del `while`, pues se supone que si se leen los resultados dentro de un `while` es porque el `SELECT` podría traer más de una fila, si cerramos la fuente de datos, no podremos seguir leyendo en una posible 2ª, 3ª ... iteracción del bucle. Por tanto habría que:

1. Recuperar en una variable todos los posibles datos del `SELECT`
2. Cerrar el estatemente del `SELECT`
3. Usar la variable que contiene los datos para lanzar ahora el `UPDATE`

El siguiente código funciona, pero debo decir que en este tipo de casos lo más óptimo sería usar transacciones. De ese modo, se prepara el `UPDATE` una sola vez, y luego se manda a ejecutar con todos los datos que hay que actualizar.

Dejo aquí un código funcional, sin meterme en el terreno de las transacciones porque quizá se alejaría demasiado del código original, pero hago constar esa posibilidad para que se busque más adelante la forma de optimizar el código.

Hay otras mejoras, como el control inicial de los datos que son recibidos vía POST. También cuando he podido en evitado el uso de `ñ` en nombre de variables. Sugeriría que lo evites también al nombrar tus tablas, columnas, nombres de elementos HTML etc. No sólo la `ñ`, sino también las palabras acentuadas, ya que en algunos escenarios podrían darte problemas. Por otra parte, todo el código `mysqli` lo he puesto en el estilo orientado a objetos. Tu código original mezclaba los dos estilos, lo cual es una mala práctica. El estilo orientado a objetos es más claro, más bonito, más moderno y menos *verbose*  que el estilo procedural.

Espero sea de utilidad.

```
    $contra =     ( empty($_POST['contraseñaanterior']) ) ? NULL : $_POST['contraseñaanterior'];
    $contrasena = ( empty($_POST['nuevacontraseña']) )    ? NULL : $_POST['nuevacontraseña'];
    $user =       ( empty($_POST['usuario']) )            ? NULL : $_POST['usuario'];
    if ( $contra && $contrasena && $user ) {
        $contrasenahash = password_hash($contrasena, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
        $query = $con->prepare("SELECT  contraseña from usuarios where idusuario = ?");
        $query->bind_param("i",$user);
        $query->execute();
        $query->bind_result($pwd);

        $arrDatos=array();
        while (mysqli_stmt_fetch($query)) {
            if ( password_verify($contra,$pwd) ) {
                $arrDatos[]=$pwd;
            }
        }
        $query->close();

        foreach ($arrDatos as $row){
            $sqlUpdate="UPDATE `analisis`.`usuarios` SET `contraseña` = ?  WHERE `idusuario` = ?";
            if ( $update = $con->prepare($sqlUpdate) ){
                $update->bind_param("si",$contrasenahash,$user);
                if ( !$update->execute() ) {
                    echo "Error  (" . $update->errno . ") " . $update->error;
                }else{
                    echo "contraseña actualizada";
                    $update->close();
                }
            }else{
                echo "Error preparando Update: ".$con->error;  
                break;
            }
          }
    }else{
        echo "Revisa los datos enviados, algunos son nulos";
    }
```